# Making query in Objective C using NSRails

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, nsrails

The tutorial video for [NSRails](http://nsrails.com/) only shows how to get all records and create records.

How do you make a query (get request with some parameters)?

Comment: Please, _please_ tell me they didn't make a third party framework with `NS` as their class prefix.

Answer (score -1):

NSRails has a lot of other documentation, beyond just the video:

- [github readme](https://github.com/dingbat/nsrails/blob/master/readme.md)
- [github wiki](https://github.com/dingbat/nsrails/wiki)
- [documentation](http://dingbat.github.io/nsrails/Classes/NSRRemoteObject.html)

As for some specifics...

- The CRUD tasks are laid out in the [documentation](http://dingbat.github.io/nsrails/Classes/NSRRemoteObject.html#tasks).
- The github readme displays an example in its second code block at the top of the document:

  `Post *postNumber1 = [Post remoteObjectWithID:1 error:&error];`

Comment: Thanks. I've checked the documentations, but I couldn't find it. I'm aware about remoteObjectWithID, but it won't be useful for a search feature in the app. What I want is for example to get Posts by authors whose name contains "John"? Thanks.